# How to debug only the code I wrote in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, debugging

I am debugging my app in Xcode but it is getting so hard to do because it is also debugging some code I did not write and it is taking so long:

[image]

I would like to exclude all these code lines from debugging.

Any ideas?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  CG.setId(indexPath.row) //I want to start to debug the app from this line
  performSegue(withIdentifier: "sgShowIssue", sender: self)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've found yourself inside assembly code like this, you can escape back up the call stack using the "Step Out" debug control:

[image: Step Out debug control]

You can generally avoid diving into code you don't want to see by using the Step-Over control:

[image]

Comment: That worked, thank you! I always use the Step-Over control though. Also, I have a performSegue that loads another UIView and after clicking the "Step Out" control the debug stopped, I mean, it didn't go to the another Swift file. Is that normal?

Comment: what am I trying to debug is the code the app runs after selecting a row in a tableview (it loads another UIViewController)

Comment: I have just added the code I'm trying to debug in my main post, so you will see it better.

Comment: Loading another view controller is a very complicated and asynchronous step, and most of it is in compiled code. You're not going to be able to trace through the entire process by stepping in the debugger. Anything that draws on the screen at all is going to happen after the last point you can get to by stepping (after pressing "next instruction" probably a few thousand times). Instead, what you generally do is place lots of breakpoints in your code where you think it might jump to next.

Comment: Understood, I'll place breakpoints where I think it might jump next then. Thank you for your help!